# National Nutrition Database

Tags: nutrition

Does anyone know if there is a comprehensive, public and up-to-date database containing nutritional information for food products (both general and brand-specific)?

Comment: Is this question not off-topic?

Comment: Asking a question as to the location of comprehensive nutritional information on a site based on the topic of nutrition and viewed by thousands of people who are knowledgable on the topic and know of such resources. I'm not sure how I could be any more on topic!!!!

Comment: Generally, questions about nutritional information that are not related to fitness are considered off-topic as described in the faq (http://fitness.stackexchange.com/faq). They're often closed soon after being asked: (http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5818/how-effective-and-safe-are-energy-drinks, http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5798/why-is-there-methanol-in-ginseng-tablet, http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5792/what-is-the-biological-half-life-of-fried-foods).

Comment: @Sancho is correct that your question is unrelated to fitness or exercise. On top of that your question is basically asking for a list of answers, which should never be your goal. So the more important question is: what do you need the database for? And if that goal has a relation to exercise, how can we help you reach that goal instead?

Comment: Fine, I guess I misunderstood the point of this site. So are questions related strictly to fitness banned too if the question doesn't involve anything related to nutrition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are 3 links - I'm not sure what your intent is, if it's to track your daily intake you might be better off using a foodtracker, such as at LiveStrong.com.

- http://ndb.nal.usda.gov/
- http://www.ars.usda.gov/main/site_main.htm?modecode=12-35-45-00
- http://fnic.nal.usda.gov/nal_display/index.php?info_center=4&tax_level=1